# XMPPRoster will not post new buddy to XMPP server

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm trying to add a new buddy to the user's roster using this line of code:

```
XMPPJID jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@localhost",
                                      addBuddyTextField.text]];
[appDelegate.xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:addBuddyTextField.text];
```

This works. The other users gets the subscription request notice, he can accept it and everything works fine. The new buddy will be added into the `XMPPRosterMemoryStorage` and will show on the `[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage unsortedUsers]` NSArray so that the current roster with all his buddys can be presented on the UI.

But once the users logs out and restarts the application the whole roster is gone, with all his buddys he added. `[XMPPRoster fetchRoster]` and the following method `[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage unsortedUsers]` return an NSArray with no items in it.

Do I have to post the buddy update (add, removal) to the XMPPServer? Or is Roster not supported by my XMPPserver (ejabberd)?

Here's the code I use to activate XMPPRoster:

```
xmppRosterMemStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterMemStorage
                                         dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = false;
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true;
[xmppRoster activate:xmppStream];
[xmppRoster fetchRoster];
```

Comment: Would you post your code? Have you tried manipulating the roster with another client and then checking whether you can successfully fetch the roster from the server? ejabberd has a module for roster; have you confirmed that it's enabled?

Comment: mod_roster is enabled in my ejabberd.cfg. And this is how I activate the XMPProster: http://pastebin.com/hmRRXuth. Adium seems to add the contacts correctly and is able to retrieve them after a logout/login. Even if I add the buddy using Adium and then login with the same account using my app the xmpproster is empty.

Comment: Well, the delegates from the XMPPRoster get fired but the roster is empty. The didReceivePresence delegate method that belongs to the XMPPStream indeed returns if a buddy is available or is subscribing or whatever, but this is not fulfilling the matter of a real roster.

Comment: If you add a buddy in your code, does it show up in Adium?

Comment: Added buddies in my app show also up on the buddy list in Adium (same account). Therefore, the problem should lie in retrieving the roster in my app. To be clear: I'm fetching the roster and waiting for the delegate message `xmppRosterDidChange` or `xmppRosterDidPopulate` to get fired. But they only get fired once a user in my roster changes his presence. Fetching the roster (waiting some time) and check the roster for any users in it using `unsortedUsers` returns an empty array.

Comment: Do you invoke the code which sets up the roster before or after you authenticate?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, autoFetchRoster is on, so it doesn't matter whether or not you directly invoke -fetchRoster.

Comment: I went desperate so turned on autoFetchRoster and invoked manually fetchRoster...

Comment: Hey Hi @Phil I'm trying to add new user to the roster list using the same code you used. But i'm not successful. Also initialized the roster as you have done. Not sure what's wrong. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussion above, it sounds like your server is getting your roster requests just fine. Using your setup code I can't reproduce the problem you're having.

You could try turning on logging and seeing if reading the protocol log helps you understand what's happening:

```
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    ...
```

Or try my test code with your server, and if the problem goes away, start working from there:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "XMPPFramework.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "DDLog.h"

static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;

NSString * const XMPPAuthenticationMethodPlain = @"Plain";
NSString * const XMPPAuthenticationMethodDigestMD5 = @"Digest-MD5";

NSString * const OptionHostName = @"...";
NSUInteger const OptionPort = 5222;
BOOL const OptionOldSchoolSSL = NO;
NSString * const OptionJID = @"...";
NSString * const OptionAuthenticationMethod = @"Digest-MD5";
NSString * const OptionPassword = @"...";

@interface AppDelegate () <XMPPStreamDelegate, XMPPRosterMemoryStorageDelegate>

@property (retain) XMPPStream *xmppStream;
@property (retain) XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *xmppRosterMemStorage;
@property (retain) XMPPRoster *xmppRoster;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
    [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    self.xmppStream.hostName = OptionHostName;
    self.xmppStream.hostPort = OptionPort;
    self.xmppStream.myJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:OptionJID];

    self.xmppRosterMemStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    self.xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:self.xmppRosterMemStorage
                                             dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.xmppRoster activate:self.xmppStream];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (OptionOldSchoolSSL)
        [self.xmppStream oldSchoolSecureConnect:&error];
    else
        [self.xmppStream connect:&error];
}

-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.xmppStream removeDelegate:self];
    [self.xmppStream disconnect];
}

-(void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    Class authClass = nil;
    if ([OptionAuthenticationMethod isEqual:XMPPAuthenticationMethodPlain])
        authClass = [XMPPPlainAuthentication class];
    else if ([OptionAuthenticationMethod isEqual:XMPPAuthenticationMethodDigestMD5])
        authClass = [XMPPDigestMD5Authentication class];
    else {
        DDLogWarn(@"Unrecognized auhthentication method '%@', falling back on Plain",
                  OptionAuthenticationMethod);
        authClass = [XMPPPlainAuthentication class];
    }
    id<XMPPSASLAuthentication> auth = [[authClass alloc] initWithStream:sender
                                                               password:OptionPassword];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![sender authenticate:auth error:&error])
        NSLog(@"Error authenticating: %@", error);
}

-(void)xmppRosterDidPopulate:(XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *)sender {
    NSLog(@"users: %@", [sender unsortedUsers]);
    // My subscribed users do print out
}

@end
```

It also works if I move the roster setup code to `-xmppStreamDidAuthenticate`, however I do need to manually invoke `-fetchRoster` in that case.

Comment: It seems that it works now! Yep, it was a great idea from me to fetch the roster even if the client isn't connected to the server. You're awesome, noa!

Comment: hello,

when i use the ip as hostname its not authenticating.....but when i use server name its not connecting to host. it says check host name. please help

Comment: @Ronak, please post a new question.

Comment: @noa i am not able to create new question. can you come to chat